# arm direct memory operations

Tags: assembly, arm

Are there any instruction in arm that support direct memory operation?

so instead of:

```
*cc = *cc + 100;

mov r3, #0
ldr r1, [r3, #0]
add r1, r1, #100
str r1, [r3, #0]
```

does it have something like or close to:

```
add [r3, #0],#100 ;I know this is wrong in current arm instruction set
```

Comment: nope pretty much by definition right?  cisc vs risc.

Comment: It's not about CISC versus RISC; it's because ARM is a "load/store/ALU" architecture. The power of ARM is in the 3 operand instructions, plenty of registers to work with, conditional execution and the barrel shifter.

Comment: According to [ARM and Thumb-2 Instruction Set Quick Reference Card](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf) it seems that _register offset_ addressing mode is supported only in _LDR_ and _STR_ instructions

Comment: There aren't, [but there will be](http://lwn.net/Articles/650900/), in at least _some_ future 64-bit hardware...

Answer (score 4):

The [ARM instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Instruction_set) has a conventional [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) design. Accordingly it's also a [load/store architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load/store_architecture). This means that memory can be only accessed by load and store instructions. Other instructions can only have register or immediate operands.

So, no, other than load and store instructions, there are no instructions in the ARM instruction set that support memory operands.